# azure mobile app table query client

Tags: c#, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

We use azure mobile app tables as endpoints exposed to android application

However this morning we faced strange problem .

Currently we operate with default page size (50) on android as well as azure ends

$top=50&$skip=100&$orderby=id%20asc&__includeDeleted=true

However this particular Url which is generated by android sdk started breaking.

Note that, we purely query https://url/tables/testable and the rest of the part is given by azure mobile app client sdk.

if for debugging in fiddler we make skip value as 50 or 150 it works but 100 breaks. Any idea anyone?

Update:
It's android native app. with endpoints created using table controllers.

Url like https://localhost:44300/tables/testtable

Some tables have 1000's of records, and when android sdk is pulling the table. it randomly breaks, at url's similar to above mentioned one.

Comment: This is extremely strange.  Can you update your Q with some more details - specifically, what sort of mobile app are you using? (Node, ASP.NET, Easy Tables), have you done any customization to the table or the workflow (if so, what), what does the "break" entail in terms of fiddler output, and what, if anything, does the backend log if you turn on verbose logging?

Comment: updated.it's strange, because it works in fiddler,postman, and the same url also works on retry..

Comment: Is there any output from the server if you turn on diagnostic logging at the verbose level and watch the log stream in the portal?

Comment: we do have logging enabled. but it's not something we are seeing in our logs.

Comment: At this point, there is not enough information to debug.  If fiddler works for that query, then you need to attach a debugger to the android device and see what is happening in your code.  If fiddler doesn't work, then you need to step through the server code to see what is happening.  It's a debugging exercise.

Comment: @AdrianHall It's very strange. If just breaks when skip 100 records, it seems there are some issues on Azure Mobile Apps, but for randomly breaks, I doubt is it caused by some environment factors like network. Please check.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior locally, so not much I can do right now.